# Como criar uma textView por código em um local específico da activity?

Tags: java, android, textview

Gostaria de saber como escolher o local onde a `textView` criada por código irá aparecer, pois por padrão ela é criada na parte superior à esquerda da *activity*.

**activity:**

```
package genesysgeneration.classsound;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("lshdajshdlajsdkl");

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        relativeLayout.addView(tv);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar essa façanha é usando o [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), passando o método `getLayoutParams()` na *view* desejada. Abaixo segue um exemplo usando um botão simples: <kbd>Jon Snow</kbd>. Vide comentários. Veja:

```
// RelativeLayout referente ao XML
RelativeLayout relativeLayout  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);

// botão a ser positionado
Button btnJonSnow= new Button(this);
btnJonSnow.setText("Jon Snow");

// definição da largura e altura do botão
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relativeLayout.addView(btnJonSnow, layoutParams);

//propriedades do Relative Layout para o posicionamento
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btnJonSnow
  .getLayoutParams();
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
btnJonSnow.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Veja abaixo os posicionamentos básicos:

**Topo/Esquerda**

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

**Topo/Direita**

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

**Rodapé/Esquerda**

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
```

**Rodapé/Direita**

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

**Center vertical/horizontal**

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber mais detalhes e posicionamentos, veja [**na documentação**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).