# Como criar components dinamicamente, sendo eles criados em relação a outros components já existentes?

Tags: java, android

Em um projeto no android studio, ao clicar em um dos 2 buttons existentes na activity (01 e 101) um TextView exibe uma resposta correspondente à escolha.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que um novo button fosse criado logo abaixo desse segundo TextView (resposta):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que podem ser feitas as seguintes referências (sendo **position** o RelativeLayout de posicionamento):

Topo esquerda => `position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);`

Topo direita => `position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`

Rodapé esquerda => `position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);`

Rodapé direita => `position.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`

Centro vertical/horizontal => `position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`

**ALÉM DE OUTRAS...**

Aprendi isso graças a resposta do Ack Lay nessa pergunta [Como criar uma textView por código em um local específico da activity?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191693/como-criar-uma-textview-por-c%C3%B3digo-em-um-local-espec%C3%ADfico-da-activity)

Porém não achei nada relacionado a referência a outro component presente na activity.

**MainActivity:**

```
package genesysgeneration.chloko;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btn01, btn101;
    private TextView tv02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv02);

        btn01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn01);
        btn101=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn101);

        btn01.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn101.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn01:

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout01 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams01 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btn02 = new Button(this);
                btn02.setText("02");
                relativeLayout01.addView(btn02, layoutParams01);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position01 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn02.getLayoutParams();
                //abaixo do TEXTVIEW (tv02)

                break;

            case R.id.btn101:

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout02 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams02 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btn102 = new Button(this);
                btn102.setText("102");
                relativeLayout02.addView(btn102, layoutParams02);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position02 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btn102.getLayoutParams();
                //abaixo do TEXTVIEW (tv02)

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Uma coisa que me chamou atenção foi que que na declaração do `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams01 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` eu não consegui colocar a dimensão real da altura do meu relativelayout que no caso é **3000dp**, tive de colocar `WRAP_CONTENT`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se pode ocorrer algum problema caso eu tenha de criar mais um desses buttons e o mesmo estiver muito mais para baixo na activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

Na imagem abaixo vocês podem ver que tem um button 50x50 (dp) no topo e à esquerda no layout da activity. Abaixo dele tem outro button com a mesma dimensões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você colocar o código `btn01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` o mesmo deixará de aparecer, mas o espaço que ocupa continuará demarcado. É como se ele estivesse fisicamente lá, mas não pudesse ser visto nem sofrer qualquer tipo de interação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se você colocar o código `btn01.setVisibility(View.GONE);` o mesmo sumirá e o espaço que ocupava enquanto ativo será compensado. Todos os componentes presentes na activity que tem algum relação de posicionamento ele serão realocados, no caso do exemplo, o **btn02 subirá 50dp na vertical**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo uma imagem que explica bem como acontece a realocação das posições dos componentes quando têm ou não alguma referência com o objeto que irá sumir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem para o que eu precisava, serviu perfeitamente. No começo da activity eu setava todos os componentes que eu não queria que aparecessem com o `View.GONE` e depois ia fazendo-os reaparecer com `View.VISIBLE`.

Com as instruções dessa resposta, você não vai exatamente criar um componente depois de determinada ação, mas fazer com que ele apareça e se torne interativo. É exatamente a mesma coisa (**pelo menos para o meu caso**), pois o mesmo não vai estar ocupando espaço algum na activity e não vai estar sendo visto pelo usuário.